# VSS snapshots on SMB3 share are "orphaned" and cannot be deleted

Tags: vss, hyper-v-server-2012-r2, veeam, emc-vnx

["Screenshots in EMC and Windows GUIs"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e7DIz.png)

Server 2012 R2 cluster.
Storage for cluster is EMC VNXe 3200 (SMB3 shares, not ISCSI).
Veeam used for backups.

There are VSS snapshots on the EMC that were created by Veeam, using the 'VNX2e VSS Provider'.

There are five of these snapshots, going back several months.

I've opened a case with Veeam and EMC. Neither have come up with an answer.

Daily backups continue to work, creating snapshots, using them, then destroying them as expected. When the backups run, the snapshots are exposed to "vssadmin" or "diskshadow" commands on the Hyper-V hosts.

These orphaned snapshots do not show in "vssadmin" or "diskshadow".

I'm hoping there is a command that can be run from the HyperV host that can access and delete the orphaned snaphots (shadows).

Here are commands run on one of the HyperV hosts. Results are similar on the other host.

```
C:\vssadmin list shadows
vssadmin 1.1 - Volume Shadow Copy Service administrative command-line tool

No items found that satisfy the query.

=================================================================
C:>vssadmin list providers

vssadmin 1.1 - Volume Shadow Copy Service administrative command-line tool

Provider name: 'Microsoft CSV Shadow Copy Helper Provider'
   Provider type: Software
   Provider Id: {26d02d81-6aac-4275-8504-b9c6edc5261d}
   Version: 1.0.0.1

Provider name: 'Microsoft CSV Shadow Copy Provider'
   Provider type: Software
   Provider Id: {400a2ff4-5eb1-44b0-8a05-1fcac0bcf9ff}
   Version: 1.0.0.1

Provider name: 'VNX2e VSS Provider'
   Provider type: Hardware
   Provider Id: {58c4151c-7bfa-4fb9-aca3-e8afcde763a9}
   Version: 6.2.9200.20557

Provider name: 'Microsoft File Share Shadow Copy provider'
   Provider type: Fileshare
   Provider Id: {89300202-3cec-4981-9171-19f59559e0f2}
   Version: 1.0.0.1

Provider name: 'Microsoft Software Shadow Copy provider 1.0'
   Provider type: System
   Provider Id: {b5946137-7b9f-4925-af80-51abd60b20d5}       Version: 1.0.0.7
   Version: 1.0.0.7

=================================================================
C:\Windows\system32>vssadmin delete shadows /all

vssadmin 1.1 - Volume Shadow Copy Service administrative command-line tool
No items found that satisfy the query.
```

Comment: NOTE: The attached pic of screenshots shows one valid snapshot (recent date). That snapshot was created by Veeam during a back. That snapshot was deleted automatically when the backup completed. The other snapshots are what I need to delete.

Comment: EMC Support has resolved this. It took a couple of weeks of them working on it, along with Veeam support working on it.

In the end, EMC Support had to connect as "root" and run commands. I am including some of the (sanitized) commands below. There isn't a case where I would run these without EMC support, but I want to add the notes to this question, as someone might find this and bypass weeks of collecting logs for vendors.

Comment: 17:37:43 root@(none) spa:/cores/service> MluCli.exe  destroysnap -srvc_cmd -oid 0x900000e2f -system -fast 
DestroySnapFast(): Exit. Status: 0.


17:38:19 root@(none) spa:/cores/service> MluCli.exe  destroysnap -srvc_cmd -oid 0x9000007e7 -system -fast 
DestroySnapFast(): Exit. Status: 0.

18:28:26 root@(none) spa:/cores/service>  MluCli.exe  destroysnap -srvc_cmd -oid 0x900000e35 -system -fast 
DestroySnapFast(): Exit. Status: 0.

19:17:42 root@(none) spa:/cores/service>  MluCli.exe  destroysnap -srvc_cmd -oid 0x900000e01 -system -fast
DestroySnapFast(): Exit. Status: 0.

Comment: ' MluCli.exe poll -snap |grep -e "Identification_Key" -e '

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is resolved. See my comments above for the answer.

It did require an EMC support call, and even then took many sessions with the tech. Once he had the correct direction/commands, the problem was resolved using the commands below (with a different "oid" for each snapshot that needed to be manually deleted).

```
MluCli.exe destroysnap -srvc_cmd -oid 0x9000007e7 -system -fast
```